# Manual change orientation in iOS 6

Tags: ios6

I manual change orientation in iOS 5,everything is ok.But in iOS 6,keyboard is not change orientation.UIApplication statusBarOrientation is not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In iOS 7 SDK & Xcode 5:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `statusBarOrientation` works only when `supportedInterfaceOrientations` callback returns 0. To make your previous code work, you can set a flag to true before calling `statusBarOrientation` method. This flag can be reset once `statusBarOrientation` has been invoked.

You can return 0 from `supportedInterfaceOrientations` when you find this flag to be true.